# Parcel Editor Functions Disabled

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting, parcel, parcel-fabric

What I want to do is cut polygons into new euqal size polygons, so far the only solution I found was using the Parcel Editor. However, I cannot use any of the functions because everything is disabled and I can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

I first converted my polygons to lines and created a topology with the 6 required rules. I validated the topology and checked for errors (no errors found). I created a new Parcel Fabric for the feature dataset where I store my polygons and lines (enabled information model). Then I used the tool "Load a topology to a parcel fabric" to import the polygons into the parcel fabric. I am able to select a parcel but I can't do anything with it. I loaded the lines into the parcel fabric as well but it doesn't change anything. Neither does using the workflow function.
I also have some red exlamation marks in the table of contents but I don't know how to change that. (see image)

Does anyone know how to solve this or another way to split polygons into eual size smaller polygons?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Read the [HowTo:  Remove red exclamation points and relocate an ArcMap data source](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/16476)

> Instructions provided describe how to remove red exclamation points
>   and relocate an ArcMap data source. When data has been relocated after
>   the creation of an ArcMap .mxd, relative path names no longer work. A
>   red exclamation point appears next to the feature classes in the
>   ArcMap table of contents.